# selenium wait function is not waiting for the specified element

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

In page 1 I want to click one element and On page 2 I want to click one more element
so after clicking the 1st element in page1, I apply wait function for the second element in page2.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("page2 element xpath")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("page2 element xpath")).click();
```

But once I click the 1st element in page1 wait is waiting for the second element in page1 itself and not moving to page 2 .is there any solution for this

Comment: can share your code in details?

Comment: may be clicking on 1st element on page 1 is not working. please check it

Comment: Is the page changing for you or not?

Comment: oBrowser.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='desktop_view']/li[4]/div[2]/a")).click(); 
   
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrap']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a")));
   oBrowser.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrap']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();

Comment: if i use Thread.sleep(1000); before wait then it will work but i dont want to use thread sleep

Comment: can u share the URL

Answer (score 0):

Using this Code my problem is solved.Its wait 30 for the element.Hope it will help you

```
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(wd, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wr‌ap']/div[2]/div[1]/d‌​iv/div/div[2]/ul/li[‌​4]/a")));
element.click();
```

Comment: (new WebDriverWait(wd, 30)) add this code before condition.Its working for me